# Remove List from Vector getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, collections, iterator, concurrentmodification

I have tried to remove the list from a vector like below.

```
public class StringVectorTest {

private final List<String> stringVector = new Vector<String>();

@Test
public void listRemoveTest(){

    List<String> list = stringVector.subList(0, 2);

    stringVector.removeAll(list);

    Assert.assertEquals(stringVector.size(), 3);
}

@Before
public void fillList(){
    stringVector.add("ABC");
    stringVector.add("DEF");
    stringVector.add("GEH");
    stringVector.add("IJK");
    stringVector.add("LMN");
}
```

}

while i run the test i am getting the below error

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.SubList.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:752)
at java.util.SubList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:682)
at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:284)
at java.util.SubList.iterator(AbstractList.java:678)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.contains(AbstractCollection.java:82)
at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.contains(Collections.java:1563)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.removeAll(AbstractCollection.java:336)
at java.util.Vector.removeAll(Vector.java:853)
```

I know that i have to use an `Iterator` to overcome this `ConcurrentModificationException` can anyone please let me know how i should use it in a efficient manner / best practice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it as below:

```
public void listRemoveTest() {
    stringVector.subList(0, 2).clear();
    Assert.assertEquals(stringVector.size(), 3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)'s javadoc:

*This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.
For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances. Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do this are known as **fail-fast iterators**, as they fail quickly and cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.*

*Note that this exception **does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread**. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, **if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.***

The latter is exactly what you are doing (see the stack trace you posted). As the [subList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method returns a **view** of the list, the returned list from this method is backed by your `stringVector`, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in `stringVector` and vice-versa.

So you should use this "view" to delete the elements:

```
@Test
public void listRemoveTestClearingSubList(){
    stringVector.subList(0, 2).clear();    
    Assert.assertEquals(stringVector.size(), 3);
}
```

because with a iterator is a bit trickier and uglier:

```
@Test
public void listRemoveTestClearingWithIterator(){
    Iterator<String> it = stringVector.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 && it.hasNext(); i++) {
        it.next();
        it.remove();
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(stringVector.size(), 3);
}
```